# How can I use sharedPreferences in an Array of custom checkbox?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-checkbox

I have a question about the checkbox and sharedPreferences. That I want to do is: I have a dynamic list of data with a checkbox in every row. I have a method that let me only enable one of this checkbox and disable all the rest of checkbox.

My problem is that I want to store the checkbox that I selected in the preferences.  When the user come back to this screen has to have the same enable checkbox.

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences inside of the method but it doesn't work, or is another way more easy to do this...

Thanks in advance.

```
protected CheckBox checkBox;
private ArrayList<CheckBox> mCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();


   protected void addView(final listJson ljson){    
.
.
.
.
.
        checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String restoredText = prefs.getString(PREF_CHECKBOX_SELECT, null);
        checkBox.setChecked(prefs.getBoolean(restoredText, false));



        mCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (((CheckBox)view).isChecked())
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mCheckBoxes.size(); i++) {
                        if (mCheckBoxes.get(i) == view){
                            selected_position = i;

                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            edit.putInt(PREF_CHECKBOX_SELECT, selected_position);
                            edit.commit();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), greetings.Name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            mCheckBoxes.get(i).setChecked(false);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    selected_position=-1;
                }
            }

        });
}
```

Comment: Considering that SharedPreferences only writes/reads an XML file, you're kinda stuck with plain text.  As such, you may want to just write your array out to a comma delimited string, then split it when you read it back in.

Comment: is this your settings Activity?

Comment: No, this is a simple activity where I have all the code of this screen. And, now, that I want to do is enable one checkbox and when you come back to this screen continue enable unless you change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

1) add a tag

```
checkBox.setTag(myStringToSet);
```

2) get this tag

```
if(checkBox.getTag().equals(yourString)){
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }
```